# Relation between Euler Characteristic and Homology Groups of CW-complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was trying to solve this exercise from Brendon's Topology and Geometry book:

If $X$ is a finite $CW$-complex of dimension $2$, and if $X$ is simply connected, then show that $\chi(X)$ determines $H_2(X)$ completely. What are the possibly values for $\chi(X)$ in this case?

What I did was to use that $X$ is path connected, then $H_0(X)=\mathbb Z$, and $X$ simply connected implies $H_1(X)=0$, then I have $rank~ H_2(X)=\chi(X)-1$, then follows that $\chi(X)\geq 1$. But I can't see how to determine $H_2(X)$ only by its rank.

Any advice in how to proced?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prove there's no torsion in $H_2$ of a 2-dimensional complex.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that it could be related, but this exercise comes before torsion on the book, so I will prefer to look to a proof using things that he have used so far.

Comment: The conclusion of your problem is essentially the same as saying that there is no torsion in $H_2$. I sincerely doubt you're not supposed to say that. (Bredon's book doesn't always have entirely self-contained exercises, if I recall.)

Comment: Ok, I will look foward to learn about torsion and try to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try describing $H_2(X)$ in terms of the cellular chain complex of $X$, using the fact that $X$ has no 3-cells.

A full answer is hidden below.

> Since $X$ is 2-dimensional, $H_2(X)$ is just the kernel of the differential $C_2(X)\to C_1(X)$ on the cellular chain complex (since $C_3(X)=0$).  So $H_2(X)$ is a subgroup of $C_2(X)$, and since $C_2(X)$ is free, $H_2(X)$ must be free as well.  Thus it is determined up to isomorphism by its rank.